# google script Missing ; before statement. (anonymous)@ Auth.gs:12

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to connect google sheet to "Firebase RealTime Database" I am not not able to get the data. I tried to deploy as web app and whenever I use the deployed link it show `Missing ; before statement. (line 12, file "Auth", project "FirestoreApp")` . Here is the Url for deployed [googlesheetlink](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz2KORH40zoYo2eIOe04CMsRx9ffx6GOM6Z3DENxNM2iyoKvQjnSPvBtg7h581KgUONIA/exec).
My code is as follows :

```
function getEnvironment() {
 var environment = {
   spreadsheetID: "",
   firebaseUrl: ""
 };
 return environment;
}

// Creates a Google Sheets on change trigger for the specific sheet
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(sheetID) {
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 var triggerExists = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   if (triggers[i].getTriggerSourceId() == sheetID) {
     triggerExists = true;
     break;
   }
 }

 if (!triggerExists) {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("importSheet")
     .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
     .onChange()
     .create();
 }
}

// Delete all the existing triggers for the project
function deleteTriggers() {
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
 }
}

// Initialize
function initialize(e) {
 writeDataToFirebase(getEnvironment().spreadsheetID);
}

// Write the data to the Firebase URL
function writeDataToFirebase(sheetID) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
 createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(sheetID);
 var sheets = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   importSheet(sheets[i]);
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]);
 }
}

// A utility function to generate nested object when
// given a keys in array format
function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
 lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
 for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
   key = keyPath[i];
   if (!(key in obj)) obj[key] = {};
   obj = obj[key];
 }
 obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
}

// Import each sheet when there is a change
function importSheet() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var name = sheet.getName();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 var dataToImport = {};

 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
   dataToImport[data[i][0]] = {};
   for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
     assign(dataToImport[data[i][0]], data[0][j].split("__"), data[i][j]);
   }
 }

 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

 var firebaseUrl =
   getEnvironment().firebaseUrl + sheet.getParent().getId() + "/" + name;
 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, token);
 base.setData("", dataToImport);
}
```

and
appscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "FirestoreApp",
        "version": "33",
        "libraryId": "1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw",
        "developmentMode": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  },
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

For the reference I have followed : https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/sync-google-sheets-to-a-firebase-realtime-database/64211

Can anyone help what I am missing.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: It doesn't look that you have included the Auth file that is the one throwing the error. Please add a [mcve]. Please bear in mind that question should be self-contained, this means that all the relevant details should be included directly into the question body.

Comment: Doesn't the `token` used in `var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, token)` have to be your firebase secret and not the oauth token of the script file? [ref](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/reference?authuser=0)